# Core Data Fetched Properties with SQLite store

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data

In the Core Programming Data Guide under the [Fetched Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW7) section there is a paragraph that states the following.

> The most significant constraint is that you cannot use substitutions to change the structure of the predicate—for example you cannot change a LIKE predicate to a compound predicate, nor can you change the operator (in this example, LIKE [c]). **Moreover, in Mac OS X version 10.4, this only works with the XML and Binary stores as the SQLite store will not generate the appropriate SQL.**

The last sentence states "this only works in XML and Binary stores". Is this saying that **Fetched Properties** only work in XML and Binary stores or some other part of the documentation?

Can you use fetched properties with a SQLite store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short: yes, you can use fetched properties with an SQLite store.

This paragraph refers to "substitution", which is described in the two preceding paragraphs. It basically says that Core Data allows substitutions for predicate expressions, like changing Cambridge to Durham, but disallows changing predicates types. So once you've setup a predicate

```
A like B
```

`A` and `B` can change, but `like` can't.

The bit about OS X 10.4 means that expression substitution is available for XML and Binary stores, but not SQL stores. Later versions of the OS support substitution for SQL stores as well.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, after reading it about 5 times and crossing my eyes I was pretty sure it was speaking of OSX 10.4 and SQLite stores as a combination